# How to get the latitude and longitude (map icon) from a website using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, latitude-longitude

I am trying to scrape a website to find the latitude and longitude of that place. The map icon is available on the website. The map icon when clicked redirects to the justdial map. The icon in the website is as

[image]

The inspect element for the map icon is

```
<a title="Map for JICE Academy For Excellence Pvt Ltd, Vijayanagar" href="javascript:;" onclick="view_map('080PXX80.XX80.121102122047.B3M5', 'map', 'Bangalore');
                                                        _ct('map', 'dtpg');">
                                        <span class="ico-mapicn"></span>
                                        <span class="wrtrvtxt">Map</span>
</a>
```

It seems to me like view_map is a function and its first argument is the coordinates. I scraped this using

```
url = "https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Race-Coaching-Institute-Pvt-Ltd-Hosur-Road/080PXX80-XX80-170420162628-Z6C1_BZDET?xid=QmFuZ2Fsb3JlIEJhbmsgRXhhbSBUdXRvcmlhbHM="
wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
wd.get(url)
ele = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="mapicn"]')
print(ele.get_attribute('onclick'))
```

But I am unable to figure out what format it is. Is there any other way I can get the exact lat and log of that place?

Comment: I think you should focus your question on latitude-longitude, not on selenium. you are asking what in the world does `080PXX80.XX80.121102122047.B3M5` mean!!!

Comment: It also focuses on the question that is there any way we can extract lat long using selenium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latitude and longitude is not available in the page, to get it you can emulate the post request to `https://..../functions/maps.php` or intercept the XMLHttpRequest

```
url = "https://......."
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
wd.get(url)
wd.execute_script('''
(function(open) {
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.responseURL.indexOf('maps.php') > -1){
                window.latlong = this.responseText
            }
        }, false);
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
''')

wd.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="mapicn"]').click()

latlong = wd.execute_async_script('var theData = arguments[0]; theData(latlong)')
print(latlong)
# {"lil":"12.889135400000","lon":"77.639586800000"}
```

Comment: I need latitude and longitude. My code is giving me "080PXX80.XX80.121102122047.B3M5" but I don't need this, I need real latitude and longitude which redirects me to the map.

Comment: its enough and you're welcome. it inject javascript to the page then all Ajax or XMLHttpRequest requests is redirected to that function.

Comment: That's a good answer but consider using `execute_async_script` to avoid the need for polling for it.

Comment: @pguardiario I just know it, thanks for you input. answer edited.